# Display Dictionary in List

Tags: swift, swiftui

using SwiftUI, I am making a request to a server to get data. My call to the server is good. However, the app is not displaying the data in the View.

I am attempting to display value(s) from the dictionary COURSE, which is part of the struct RESULT, in the list. What is wrong with my code?

the code:

```
// an array of what comes back from the server
struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}

// this is what comes back from the server
struct Result: Codable, Hashable {
    var STATUS_CODE : String
    var STATUS_MESSAGE : String
    var COURSE: [String : String] = ["ID" : "", "TITLE" : "", "DATE" : "", "DEPT" : "", "CATEGORY" : "", "COURSE_URL" : "", "COURSE_ID" : ""]
    
}


struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var results = [Result]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.self) { item in
            VStack() {
                Text(item.COURSE["TITLE"] ?? "n/a")

            }// end VStack
        }// end List
        .task {
            await loadData()
        }// end task
    }// end some View


func loadData() async {
        // set url
        guard let url = URL(string:
                                "theurl.com")
        else {
            print("Invalid url")
        
            
        return
        }
        
        let json: [String: String] = ["ACTION" : "GET_COURSES"]
        let jsonData = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json)
        
        var request = URLRequest(url: url)
        request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        request.httpBody = jsonData
        
        
        
        // this is what does the call
        do {
            
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(for: request)
            
             
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from:
                                                                data) {
                results = decodedResponse.results
            }
        } catch {
            print("invalid data")
        }
    }
}// end ContentView
```

This question is different than the recommended post because this question asks about looping through multiple dictionaries as opposed to just one dictionary.

Comment: what does loadData do? Please share the code and do you get any errors when downloading or decoding?

Comment: I do not get any errors. I will share that code.

Comment: Remove the question mark in `try?` and replace `print("invalid data")` with `print(error)`. And please add CodingKeys to get rid of the ugly UPPER_SNAKE_CASE names.

Comment: The ugly names are used to match up with the JSON and server side variables. Wasn't my choice. Working with what was given to me.

Comment: That's why I wrote ***please add CodingKeys*** to map the keys to swiftier names.

Comment: That example demonstrates looping through one dictionary. I will need to loop through multiple dictionaries...first step is to create an array from the dictionary. From there, I am assuming that I would need to create a new array to hold the arrays. Is this a correct assumption?

Comment: Looping through many dictionaries will be messy and slow. You should use models, JSON strings can be turned into Codable models

Comment: That's what I'm doing. The Result struct has the COURSE dictionary in it. I receive the entire RESULT from the server, but only need to display a few items from the Dictionary.

Comment: There would only be 6 - 8 dictionaries, max, looped through.

Comment: 1 is borderine, 2 is max. But if you know how to loop through one you can try as many as you want but you will start running into build issues at around 2-3.